# How to use pm2 to autorestart my discord bot

Tags: discord.js, pm2

So my discord bot would crash if someone did a wrong command. I did some googling and after I did some research I found pm2. I heard it could run "node ." automatically to start my bot if it crashed, but I don't know how to use it. Does anyone know how to use pm2?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **npm** or **yarn** to get app.

```
$ npm install pm2@latest -g
# or
$ yarn global add pm2
```

Then you can start procces with **pm2 start name**

```
cd main_file_folder_path
pm2 start app.js
```

**List of process**

`$ pm2 list`

**stop process**

`$ pm2 stop 0`

**Restart process:**

`$ pm2 restart 0`

**Show info about process**

`$ pm2 show 0`

**Delete process**

`$ pm2 delete 0`

Answer (score 1):

Once you have PM2 started and your processes running through it, run

`pm2 startup`

to initialize the automatic startup.  This command will save your current persistence but if you need to change it later you can run:

`pm2 save`

It simply starts back up where you saved it so make sure all the processes are in the state you want before doing this using

`pm2 list`

(this does not change the code or your apps data at the time of the save, just the running state).

Comment: One thing to be aware of, I have had issues on my bots (running on an RPi3) where a sudden power loss restarts the bot through PM2 but fails to log into the client on startup, resulting in the appearance of running in PM2 but no response in discord.  Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution to this yet, but I've been thinking about a .catch strategy on the login that starts a short timer to try again.