# Node.js "TypeError: process.nextTick is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Is hosting a `discord.js` bot. The bot's function is using `fs.watchFile` and `fs.readFile` to monitoring changes in a text files and send Discord embed that summarises the data entries within a `target.txt` file. However, the bot always crash after running for a few hours and throwing **process.nextTick** error:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1035
   process.nextTick(resume, websocket._socket);

TypeError: process.nextTick is not a function
   at Receiver.receiverOnConclude (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1035:11)
   at Receiver.emit (node:events:526:28)
   at Receiver.controlMessage (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:576:14)
   at Receiver.getData (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:423:42)
   at Receiver.startLoop (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:148:22)
   at Receiver._write (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:83:10)
   at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
   at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
   at Receiver.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
   at TLSSocket.socketOnData (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1187:35)
```

All these code is working except getting the process.nextTick's TypeError every few hours, unsure which part caused the error...or can the error be bypass by monkey patching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find a way to fix the discord.js script from getting that `process.nextTick` error but `pm2` npm package can at least prevent script from stopping.

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/

[How to use pm2 to autorestart my discord bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59888805/how-to-use-pm2-to-autorestart-my-discord-bot)